# Get the list of azure storage accounts that use TLS_1.0

Tags: azure, azure-storage

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-support-tls-will-end-by-31-october-2024-2/

Azure support for TLS 1.0 and 1.1 ends 31 October 2024. I need to upgrade every storage account  `MinimumTlsVersion` property.

While there are ways to do this (`pwsh`, Portal, ARM), I was curious if there is a way to get the list of all storages that uses TLS < 1.2.

```
# Ensure you're logged in to Azure
# Connect-AzAccount

# Set your Azure subscription ID
$subscriptionId = "your-subscription-id"

# Select the Azure subscription
Select-AzSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId

# Get all Storage accounts in the subscription
$storageAccounts = Get-AzStorageAccount

# Initialize an empty array to hold Storage accounts with TLS 1.0
$storagesUsingTls1_0 = @()

foreach ($storage in $storageAccounts) {
    try {
        # Attempt to fetch the storage account properties, including the minimum TLS version
        $storageProps = Get-AzStorageAccount -ResourceGroupName $storage.ResourceGroupName -AccountName $storage.StorageAccountName
        $tlsSetting = $storageProps.Encryption.MinimumTlsVersion
        
        # Check if the TLS version is 1.0
        if ($tlsSetting -eq "TLS1_0") {
            # Add to the list
            $storagesUsingTls1_0 += $storage
        }
    } catch {
        Write-Host "Error retrieving TLS settings for storage account: $($storage.StorageAccountName)"
    }
}

# Output the Storage accounts using TLS 1.0
$storagesUsingTls1_0 | Format-Table StorageAccountName, ResourceGroupName, Location, @{Name="TLS Version"; Expression={$_.Encryption.MinimumTlsVersion}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your question is just to see all the storage accounts with the TLS version not being 1.2 I would advice you to use the Azure Resource Graph Explorer. It is available in the Azure Portal (just search for it) and allows you to query your Azure Resources. The below query would give you all your storage accounts not on TLS version 1.2:

```
resources
| where type == "microsoft.storage/storageaccounts"
| where properties['minimumTlsVersion'] != "TLS1_2"
| project name, resourceGroup, properties.minimumTlsVersion
```